# WebSphere 8.5.5 Linux: Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404

Tags: websphere-8

I have a problem with 404 error with WebSphere 8.5.5 on Linux.

I am able to access the `index.jsp` page but cannot access other resources (e.g. rest services). I keep getting:

> Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404

`enable-file-serving` is set to `true`.

The same web application deploys fine and all resources are available with Windows WebSphere but not Linux version.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: [9/9/17 13:04:05:493 EDT] 00000086 PageNotFound  W org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CXProcessEnterpriseCloud/api/rest/deploymentService/processes/MyProcess/cd] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringREST'

Comment: This is the relevant section from my web.xml:

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured it out. It was a silly mistake on my part. The value of the applicationContext file was being constructed by a environment variable with incorrect case. i.e. instead of OnPremise, it was onPremise. Changing the value of the environment variable resolved my issue.